# How to do page numbering in footer htmls with wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: laravel, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, snappy, laravel-snappy

i m using snappypdf and i managed to add an html footer to my file with this code in my Laravel controller:

```
      ->setOption('footer-html', view('front.mail_templates.layouts.emailFooter'))->setOption('margin-bottom',17)
```

but now i want to add page numbering to it, and after looking i found this solution:

```
      ->setOption('footer-right', "Page [page] of [toPage]")
```

The problem is i want these two to appear in my pdf but i can't make them work together they work separately but if together only html footer show and page numbering is invisible , I hovered over an empty space by chance and after copying and pasting it elsewhere, i found out it was the page number printed transparently. so is it possible to make them apear both in my footer? or any other suggestions?

[image]

**EDIT**

here is my footer html code :

[image]
every thing worked fine untill i added the javascript code, now it generates the following error : he exit status code '-1073741819' says something went wrong

Comment: you didn't  understand my problem, i want to display page nim using javascript but my wkhtmltopdf is always returning an error i cant get it to work in my footer html page

Comment: i can't wait for them to fix is, so i found a work-around using a script that people said it worked for them, but i cant get it  to work for me because as soon as i add a js code or onload in my html it generates an error: The exit status code '-1073741819' says something went wrong

Comment: @KJ i updated my code please help me out

Comment: there is no content id because the page number position is defined by the commande :                 ->setOption('footer-right', "Page [page] / [toPage]")
so i don't have to add anything to my HTML code, although i tried forcing all the text in my footer to look black but it didn't appear